# 'Cannot cast from Object to int' error when I'm sure the data is an integer

Tags: java

I'm sure I'm doing something really dumb and basic here but I can't seem to figure this out.  I basically have a method that takes a bunch of numbers, does some work and returns a List of integers.

I then take that list and send it to a method to do some more work on but when I was getting errors because JVM thinks its an object. Here's a simple example(I'm editing it a bit so you get the idea and its not super long):

```
public static List normalizer_list(double[] data) {
    List normalizer_list = new ArrayList();
    for (double current_data : data) {
        Integer modified_data = (int) (current_data *1000);
        normalizer_list.add(modified_data);
    }
    return normalizer_list;
}


private static void do_some_work(List normalizer_list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for (int i = 0; i < norm_data.size(); i++) {
        Integer current_norm_data = (int) normalizer_list.get(i);
```

At first I tried to do math with norm_data.get(i) but it gave me errors because it thought it was a object, so I tried to cast it to an Integer and it says I can't do that.  What am I doing wrong(is it the way I'm using the list?)

Comment: You code wont compile. In the method do_some_work should the variable be norm_data or normalizer_list??? I think you have mixed up variable names here

Comment: @Sean sorry your right..but in my code its fine, I just changed it in the answer to make it shorter/easier for others to read. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cast as an `Integer`:

```
Integer current_norm_data = (Integer) norm_data.get(i)
```

Or better yet, make `normalizer_list` a `List<Integer>`, then accept an integer list in the `do_some_work` method.

Comment: Holy cow! I didn't realize there was a difference between int and Integer..I just figured someone who designed the language wanted me to type less.  I'm going to read up on this..

Comment: `Integer` is a wrapper, while `int` is a primitive. Since Java 1.5, you can go between them. You cannot add primitives into the usual collections. Using the `==` operator on wrapper types is dangerous. This is a really important detail of Java. So I personally do encourage more reading on this topic.

Comment: Thanks Dilium, I will read more on it.  Thanks for the answer. I learned two things, the difference between integer and int and that I need to declare the list types(even if all the content is of the same type..this is different from the python world). Thank you Dilum.

Comment: @Dilum Ranatunga Works! But why on 1 pc (int) is fine, and on 2 pc it is not?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at using List to put your data in - then getting rid of all the casting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Integer.valueOf();`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29)

```
 Integer modified_data = Integer.valueOf(current_data *1000);
```